# Allow room owners to grant write access to new users

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderator-tools

This discussion has been raised before, but it's always been about helping new users in chat rather than continuing in comments, which allows people to help new users out more instead of just denying them access to anything.

However, the context I am bringing up here is entirely different. I have a room on the site I moderate (CGCC), [APL Orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard), which is for discussion about the programming language APL. Users from the APL community frequently join discussion on SE chat and potentially contribute to SE over time as well. However, in order to get the user to actually be able to participate, since only moderators can grant access, the room owner has to ping me every time to grant access.

The thing is, I don't even check the user myself, because they have a default username, a completely empty profile, and no content on SE at all, so there's nothing I could even check for. I grant them access because that room's RO knows the user from a different place and I trust my RO's judgement to trust those users. Besides, it's a room dedicated to APL, and there's not really much harm that could come out of it in the first place; it isn't like this is our site's main chat room.

Therefore, it would make a lot of sense and be far more convenient for both me (so I don't have to grant access each time, though I don't mind bringing new users into this community) and especially the RO (so he doesn't have to ping me in our site's main chat and wait possibly hours for a moderator to be online to grant access).

Since it's been quite a while since this was last talked about, could this feature be added? Or if this is somehow "too risky" to give to ROs, who are literally entrusted with the entire chat room, could certain rooms, or certain room owners of specific rooms, be granted permission to give access to low-reputation users by moderators?

Comment: 'Or if this is somehow "too risky" to give to ROs, who are literally entrusted with the entire chat room' As a Room Owner, I can say the title sounds like more than it is. I consider it more of a first-line of defence in case moderators aren't available.

Comment: @Mast That's fair. For some rooms, I would agree; for example, I might not want my site's main chat room's owners to have this permission (not that we have any active non-moderator ROs...). But in many cases, for a room created by and solely used for a purpose that makes sense for the RO to get full control over, I'd like the ability to let a user give write access in a specific room. Hopefully that makes sense.